# Why is the dereference operator (*) also used to declare a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, syntax, dereference, notation

I'm not sure if this is a proper programming question, but it's something that has always bothered me, and I wonder if I'm the only one.

When initially learning C++, I understood the concept of references, but pointers had me confused. Why, you ask? Because of how you declare a pointer.

Consider the following:

```
void foo(int* bar)
{
}


int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    int* y = NULL;

    y = &x;
    *y = 15;     
    foo(y);

}
```

The function `foo(int*)` takes an `int` pointer as parameter. Since I've declared `y` as `int` pointer, I can pass `y` to `foo`, but when first learning C++ I associated the `*` symbol with dereferencing, as such I figured a dereferenced `int` needed to be passed. I would try to pass `*y` into `foo`, which obviously doesn't work.

Wouldn't it have been easier to have a separate operator for declaring a pointer? (or for dereferencing). For example:

```
void test(int@ x)
{
}
```

Comment: This question can't be answered, only speculated upon.

Comment: What's wrong with genuine curiosity?

Comment: @diggingforfire : Nothing, but that's not what SO is for. Try [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) for discussion-based questions.

Comment: @bmargulies It can be answered directly; the creator of C wrote a document explaining exactly why this is so.

Comment: A question can be in the form of genuine curiosity, right? In fact, I find Crashworks' answer to be just that, a direct answer to my question. So why could this only be speculated upon?

Comment: @ildjarn : telling people to go and create their own language implies I'm saying "geez c++ sucks who thought of this stupid idea", which is hardly the case here.

Comment: @ildjarn: This isn't discussion-based, there's a clear answer to the question and we've all given it.

Comment: It might make sense to take out the `phooehy` case and reduce the code to a simplified `main`. I removed `reference` from the tags, as the question does not seem to be about references at all. Although the *related* question might be: "Why is the address-of operator (&) also used to declare a reference?" It is also overloaded in a similar fashion.

Comment: @diggingforfire : I said nothing like that, so I don't know what your point is.

Comment: @ildjarn: I was referring to Tomalak Geret'kal's comment, pardon the confusion.

Comment: @Stuart : The only real answer here is the one quoting the language's creator; your answer in particular is purely subjective and subjective answers are not encouraged on SO. That was my point, and it still stands, in general.

Comment: Crashworks gave a much more helpful answer, which is why I upvoted it. But mine wasn't subjective, it came from hanging around in comp.lang.c++ and having come across the reason before from people who know more than I do :) Anyway, no worries.

Comment: Well, it depends...which are cuter, puppies or kittens?

Comment: Whichever gets me more rep, my man.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

In [The Development of the C Language](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html), Dennis Ritchie explains his reasoning thusly:

> The second innovation that most clearly distinguishes C from its
>   predecessors is this fuller type structure and especially its
>   expression in the syntax of declarations... given an object of any
>   type, it should be possible to describe a new object that gathers
>   several into an array, yields it from a function, or is a pointer to
>   it.... [This] *led to a
>   declaration syntax for names mirroring that of the expression syntax
>   in which the names typically appear.* Thus,
>
> `int i, *pi, **ppi;` declare an integer, a pointer to an integer, a
>   pointer to a pointer to an integer. The syntax of these declarations
>   reflects the observation that `i, *pi, and **ppi` all yield an `int` type
>   when used in an expression.
>
> Similarly, `int f(), *f(), (*f)();` declare
>   a function returning an integer, a function returning a pointer to an
>   integer, a pointer to a function returning an integer. `int *api[10],
>   (*pai)[10];` declare an array of pointers to integers, and a pointer to
>   an array of integers.
>
> *In all these cases the declaration of a
>   variable resembles its usage in an expression whose type is the one
>   named at the head of the declaration*.
>
> An accident of syntax contributed to the perceived complexity of the
>   language. The indirection operator, spelled * in C, is syntactically a
>   unary prefix operator, just as in BCPL and B. This works well in
>   simple expressions, but in more complex cases, parentheses are
>   required to direct the parsing. For example, to distinguish
>   indirection through the value returned by a function from calling a
>   function designated by a pointer, one writes `*fp() and (*pf)()`
>   respectively. The style used in expressions carries through to
>   declarations, so the names might be declared
>
> `int *fp(); int (*pf)();`
>
> In more ornate but still realistic cases,
>   things become worse: `int *(*pfp)();` is a pointer to a function
>   returning a pointer to an integer.
>
> There are two effects occurring.
>   Most important, C has a relatively rich set of ways of describing
>   types (compared, say, with Pascal). Declarations in languages as
>   expressive as C—Algol 68, for example—describe objects equally hard to
>   understand, simply because the objects themselves are complex. A
>   second effect owes to details of the syntax. Declarations in C must be
>   read in an `inside-out' style that many find difficult to grasp. 
>   Sethi [Sethi 81] observed that many of the nested
>   declarations and expressions would become simpler if the indirection
>   operator had been taken as a postfix operator instead of prefix, but
>   by then it was too late to change.

Comment: That is an excellent explanation, I wish we were actually being told these kind of things in class, it would've helped me understand pointers much sooner.

Comment: This is very helpful! I've always wondered about the weird syntax of function pointers. Knowing the background makes reading and writing them much easier. Love this website <3

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Shucks, too bad I can't edit it now. Well, these things do happen when  writing in a foreign language.

Comment: @diggingforfire You may also like my "graph paper and pencil" technique for reasoning with pointers (example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062853/c-pointer-assignment-question/7062888#7062888). I generally believe that learning what the machine actually does with pointers first makes learning the C abstraction easier; rather than trying to learn the abstraction first and then the concrete after.

Comment: I found the [Binking Pointer Fun](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/104/) videos informative. If I taught a curriculum I would use them.

Comment: What part of this quote explains why prefix * was selected over alternatives?

Comment: @David: None of it, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - the  "just as in BCPL and B" in BCPL all unary operators were prefix

Comment: @Mark I thought the italicised sections were meant to be special. I bet that what happened was that BCPL took this route, C followed and then C++ followed. Understanding the reasons for the very original decision would require a time machine.

Comment: @David Or you could read the rest of the linked document which describes the BCPL roots.

Comment: @Crashworks: I never once claimed that it was the former. I understand the question just fine, thanks!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Tired of working for the Tal Shiar, eh?

Answer (score 17):

The reason is clearer if you write it like this:

```
int x, *y;
```

That is, both x and *y are ints. Thus y is an int *.

Comment: Actually, this is not clearer if you expand it. I don't want to start an argument, but I'd like to point out that this syntax is bound to lead to one.

Comment: I agree that you shouldn't *use* this syntax in practice - it was merely to illustrate the point (which is the same point David makes).

Comment: Indeed, nothing against you or your answer (except perhaps the "clearer" part)

Comment: No offence taken :) Just trying to clarify.

Comment: This answer illustrates why the Q is closed as not constructive.

Comment: Probably not the clearest answer in the world, but typed on an iPad hence shorter than normal. The point I was trying to make is that if you group the * with the variable name then it becomes clearer where this syntax came from - namely the idea that by saying * y is an int, you are implying that y itself is an int *. As this answer has been borne out in practice by the reference given (and it wasn't a guess), I'm not sure where the hostility is coming from. Anyway, let's agree to disagree.

Comment: I think hostility is perhaps overstating it. But you are drawing a bit of flak because you were vocal in criticising the close votes but then produced an answer that, to my mind and it would seem to the minds of others, perfectly captures why this question is not constructive: *This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.* But yeah, let's agree to disagree!  ;-)

Answer (score 12):

That is a language decision that predates C++, as C++ inherited it from C. I once heard that the motivation was that the declaration and the use would be equivalent, that is, given a declaration `int *p;` the expression `*p` is of type `int` in the same way that with `int i;` the expression `i` is of type `int`.

Answer (score 10):

Because the committee, and those that developed C++ in the decades before its standardisation, decided that **`*` should retain its original three meanings**:

- A pointer type
- The dereference operator
- Multiplication

You're right to suggest that the multiple meanings of `*` (and, similarly, `&`) are confusing. I've been of the opinion for some years that it they are a significant barrier to understanding for language newcomers.

---

#### Why not choose another symbol for C++?

**Backwards-compatibility** is the root cause... best to re-use existing symbols in a new context than to break C programs by translating previously-not-operators into new meanings.

---

#### Why not choose another symbol for C?

It's impossible to know for sure, but there are several arguments that can be — and have been — made. Foremost is the idea that:

> when [an] identifier appears in an expression of the same form as the declarator, it yields an object of the specified type. {K&R, p216}

This is also why C programmers tend to<sup>[citation needed]</sup> prefer aligning their asterisks to the right rather than to the left, i.e.:

```
int *ptr1; // roughly C-style
int* ptr2; // roughly C++-style
```

though both varieties are found in programs of both languages, varyingly.

Comment: I don't think the committee decided anything; it was probably Dennis Ritchie when he created C.

Comment: The committee is responsible for the language we know today. Fair point, it started with DR, but that's not "C" as we know it now. And, more than much else, the C++ committee has the conscious decision for the C++ language -- Ritchie did not.

Comment: Before there was a committee, Ritchie invented that syntax. Stroustrup was not going to break backwards compatibility with C by not using it. All these decisions were made before the development of C and C++ was put under a standards body.

Comment: @BrianNeal: Fine, but the languages as we know them are governed by those committees, and those committees are -- currently -- responsible for that decision. Unless you want to credit that first protein in the primordial soup.

Answer (score 6):

Page 65 of [Expert C Programming: Deep C Secrets](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131774298) includes the following: *And then, there is the C philosophy that the declaration of an object should look like its use.*

Page 216 of [The C Programming Language, 2nd edition (aka K&R)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) includes: *A declarator is read as an assertion that when its identifier appears in an expression of the same form as the declarator, it yields an object of the specified type.*

I prefer the way van der Linden puts it.

Answer (score 6):

Haha, I feel your pain, I had the exact same problem.

I thought a pointer should be declared as `&int` because it makes sense that a pointer is an address of something.

After a while I thought for myself, every type in C can be read **backwards**, like

`int * const x`

can be read as

`x  const  *  int`

A constant `x`, when dereferenced (signaled with `*`) is of type `int`.
So something that has to be **dereferenced**, has to be a pointer.