# i want to understand how this part of code works

Tags: c

I want to understand how this part of code works i know it seems simple but I'm not good the pointer notion so anything would be helpfull

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    int main(){
        int a,b;
        int *ptr1,*ptr2;
        a=5;
        b=a;
        ptr1=&a;
        ptr2=ptr1;
        b=(*ptr2)++;
        printf("a = %d, b=%d,*ptr1=%d,*ptr2=%d\n",a,b,*ptr1,*ptr2);
    }
```

and the output is

```
a = 6 , b = 5 , *ptr1 = 6 , *ptr2 = 6.
```

i need to understund thank you

Comment: The key to understanding this is `b=(*ptr2)++;` That takes what `ptr2` is pointing to and increments it *after* accessing its value.

Comment: but the value of b was 5 and it didn't change ? why ?

Comment: @blitz Read up on the difference between `x++` and `++x`.

Comment: Because `b = (*ptr2)++;` is basically  `b = *ptr2; (*ptr2)++;` or in this case `b = a; a++;` read about the post increment operator.

Comment: Here is the flow: 1) `(*ptr2)` accesses the value of what `ptr2` is pointing to; 2) `b` is set to that value; 3) since you have post increment, *after* `b` is set to 5, *then* that value of what `ptr2` is pointing to is incremented by 1 and is now 6. If you had `++(*ptr2)` instead, then the value would be accessed, incremented, *then* assigned to `b`

Answer (score 4):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a,b;
    int *ptr1,*ptr2;
    a=5;       // Assigns value 5 to a
    b=a;       // Assigns value of a (i.e., 5) to b
    ptr1=&a;   // Assigns address of a to prt1 or ptr1 points to variable a
    ptr2=ptr1; // ptr2 holds same address as ptr1 does (i.e, address of a)

    b=(*ptr2)++;
    /* 
      Now this one is tricky.
      Look at precedence table here
        http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence
      b is assigned value of *ptr2 first and then 
        value at *ptr2 (i.e., 5) is incremented later.
      Try replacing b = (*ptr2)++ with b = ++(*ptr2). It'll print 6.
    */

    printf("a = %d, b=%d,*ptr1=%d,*ptr2=%d\n",a,b,*ptr1,*ptr2);
}
```

Let's visualize through address and value table. Suppose `int` is 1-byte or 1-unit and address space of your program begins with 100.

```
a = 5

  a    
+---+---+---+---+---+--
|  5|   |   |   |   | ...
+---+---+---+---+---+--
 100 101 102 103 104  ...

b = a

  a   b 
+---+---+---+---+---+--
|  5|  5|   |   |   | ...
+---+---+---+---+---+--
 100 101 102 103 104  ...

ptr1=&a

  a   b  ptr1 
+---+---+----+----+---+--
|  5|  5| 100|    |   | ...
+---+---+----+----+---+--
 100 101 102 103 104  ...

ptr2 holds some random address when you initialize.

int *ptr2;

  a   b  ptr1 ptr2 
+---+---+----+----+---+--
|  5|  5| 100| 234|   | ...
+---+---+----+----+---+--
 100 101 102 103 104  ...


ptr2=ptr1

  a   b  ptr1 ptr2 
+---+---+----+----+---+--
|  5|  5| 100| 100|   | ...
+---+---+----+----+---+--
 100 101 102 103 104  ...

b=(*ptr2)++

First, dereference *ptr2 and assign that to b.

  a   b  ptr1 ptr2
+---+---+----+----+---+--
|  5|  5| 100| 100|   | ...
+---+---+----+----+---+--
 100 101 102 103 104  ...
  ^            |
  |____________|

Now increment value at address 100

  a   b  ptr1 ptr2 
+---+---+----+----+---+--
|  6|  5| 100| 100|   | ...
+---+---+----+----+---+--
 100 101 102 103 104  ...
```

Hope that vizulization helps.

Read about pointer assignment here : [C++ pointer assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062853/c-pointer-assignment)

Comment: "// ptr2 points to ptr1" should be "Assigns ptr1 to ptr2".  `ptr2` does not point to `ptr1`.  Detail: "first and then" is likely, but the _order_ is not defined.  It is more like the 2 events happen in _some_ sequence_ (or not), but the _effect_ is as you have commented.  Order makes a difference should the variables access have a side effect.

Comment: How about this for `ptr2=ptr1` : ptr2 now holds the same address as ptr1 does.